# MYSQL ERROR CONCERNING UPDATING CHILD/PARENT TABLES

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys, sql-insert

So I have these tables below:

```
CREATE TABLE branch (
 branch_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
 branch_name VARCHAR(40),
 mgr_id INT,
 mgr_start_date DATE,
 FOREIGN KEY(mgr_id) REFERENCES employee(emp_id) ON DELETE SET NULL
);

CREATE TABLE branch_supplier (
 branch_id INT,
 supplier_name VARCHAR(40),
 supply_type VARCHAR(40),
 PRIMARY KEY(branch_id, supplier_name),
 FOREIGN KEY(branch_id) REFERENCES branch(branch_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

And I am trying to insert information into the branch_supplier table.

```
INSERT INTO branch_supplier VALUES(2, 'Uni-ball', 'Writing Utensils');
```

But keep getting hit with the following error:

> ER_NO_REFERENCED_ROW_2: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign
>   key constraint fails (`girrafe`.`branch_supplier`, CONSTRAINT
>   `branch_supplier_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`branch_id`) REFERENCES `branch`
>   (`branch_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)

I am just starting to learn MYSQL. Not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is quite clear. The value that you give to column `branch_supplier` in child table `branch_supplier` (here, `2`) must exist in column `branch_id` of parent table `branch`.

Either change that value to something that exists in the parent table, or insert the parent row first, then the child row.

Comment: So here is the parent table branch?

Comment: @user13485609: yes, exactly.

Comment: Forgive me as I am new to this but what would the code be to fix this error?

Comment: @user13485609: as I said: either `insert` a row in `branch` with `branch_id` `2`, or change the query that inserts into `branch_supplier` so it uses a `branch_id` that already exists in `branch`.